# How to get rid of extra columns in SWT Table

Tags: swt

[image: Here is how it appears,As you see there is a small column without any header is being created.]I have a SWT Table which has three columns.Now problem is after creating the table and populating the table with values I am seeing some extra columns and extra rows.Can anyone tell me how can I get rid of them.Below is the snippet for it.

```
String[] variables = variableString.split(NodeItemDetailsProvider.INPUT_VARIABLE + DELIMITER);
        String referenceVariables = variables.length > 1 ? variables[1] : ""; //$NON-NLS-1$
        boolean isInputAbsent = referenceVariables.equalsIgnoreCase(StringUtils.EMPTY);
        String refVarsArray[] = referenceVariables.split(NodeItemDetailsProvider.REFERENCE_VARIABLE_SEPARATOR);
        GridData gd_table = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
        int tableStyle = SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL;
        if (refVarsArray.length > 10) {
            tableStyle = SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL;
            gd_table.heightHint = 150;
            gd_table.widthHint = 450;
        }
        Table refVarTable = new Table(top, tableStyle);
        refVarTable.setLayoutData(gd_table);
        refVarTable.setHeaderVisible(false);
        refVarTable.setLinesVisible(true);
        refVarTable.setBackground(TouchstoneStyleSheet.get(ColorKey.HIGHLIGHTED_TEXT_YELLOW_BACKGROUND));
        String[] titles = { "Variable Name", "Variable Value Provided To Reference", //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
                "Variable Value Retrieved From Reference" }; //$NON-NLS-1$
        TableItem header = new TableItem(refVarTable, SWT.NONE);
        header.setBackground(TouchstoneStyleSheet.get(ColorKey.HIGHLIGHTED_TEXT_YELLOW_BACKGROUND));
        final Font font = new Font(null, StringUtils.EMPTY, 9, SWT.BOLD);
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            new TableColumn(refVarTable, SWT.NONE);
            header.setFont(i, font);
            header.setText(i, titles[i]);
        }
        for (String row : refVarsArray) {
            String values[] = row.split(NodeItemDetailsProvider.REFERENCE_INPUT_SEPARATOR);
            TableItem item = new TableItem(refVarTable, SWT.NULL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
            for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
                if (values[index].length() > 90) {
                    gd_table.widthHint = 950;
                }
                item.setText(index, values[index]);
            }
        }
        for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < titles.length; loopIndex++) {
            refVarTable.getColumn(loopIndex).pack();
        }
        refVarTable.addListener(SWT.Dispose, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                font.dispose();
            }
    });
```

Comment: What extra columns? What extra rows? What do you get, what were your expecting? What is the input to this table? Show us a proper [mcve]

Comment: In Tableviewer you can use TableColumnLayout properly to align the coloums

Comment: I want something like this table as shown in this below example ,except the extra small column to the end.http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/TableEditorexample.htm

Comment: Anybody having any inputs on how this extra spurious column can be removed without using Table Viewer?